# Split string after 1st dot and compare length of 2 array

Tags: javascript

Below is my Array :

```
var myArray = [
    {field: 'region1.mp3.california', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'region1.mp3.marines,region1.mp3.region2.mp3.california', flag: false},
    {field: 'region2.mp3.california', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'region2.mp3.abc', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'region3.mp3.abc', flag: false}, 
];

var regions = ["region1.mp3", "region2.mp3","region3.mp3"];
```

Now here data after second dots belongs to particular region.

**For eg** : **region1.mp3.california,region1.mp3.marines**

```
california and marines belongs to region1.
```

So here I am trying to compare length of regions array and myArray and according to the myarray data and regions array data length should be equal as myarray contains all region data from regions array so their length should be equal.

**Expected output : true**

I am not getting here how to compare this using `reduce` function.

```js
var myArray = [
    {field: 'region1.mp3.california', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'region1.mp3.marines,region1.mp3.region2.mp3.california', flag: false},
    {field: 'region2.mp3.california', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'region2.mp3.abc', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'region3.mp3.abc', flag: false}, 
];

var regions = ["region1.mp3", "region2.mp3","region3.mp3"];

var len1 = regions.length;
var len2 = myArray.reduce(function (p, c) {
                return p.concat(c.field.split(','));
            }, []).length;
            
            if(len1 == len2)
               console.log(true)
               else
               console.log(false)
```

Comment: Could you be clearer on the output please ? What are you trying to compare ?

Comment: + You may have the same length but not the same region in both array

Comment: *myarray contains all region data from regions array so their length should be equal.* - it's not obvious from your input

Comment: @Weedoze :I am trying to compare length of 2 arrays i.e regions and myArray.In my Array i would like to group records by common regions and then compare the length of 2 arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am first using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array containing only [`.field.split('.')\[0\]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) which mean `region1` or ´region2´ or ´region3´. This array will have the same size than `myArray`

Then I am using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove the duplicates regions. This array will only contains `region1`, `region2` and `region3`

```js
var myArray = [
    {field: 'region1.mp3.california', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'region1.mp3.marines,region1.mp3.region2.mp3.california', flag: false},
    {field: 'region2.mp3.california', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'region2.mp3.abc', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'region3.mp3.abc', flag: false}, 
];

var regions = ["region1.mp3", "region2.mp3","region3.mp3"];
var myArrayRegions = [];

myArrayRegions = myArray.map(function(o){
  return o.field.split('.')[0];
}).filter(function(item, pos, self) {
    return self.indexOf(item) == pos;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(myArrayRegions));
console.log(JSON.stringify(regions));
```

**Detailled code**

```js
var myArray = [
    {field: 'region1.mp3.california', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'region1.mp3.marines,region1.mp3.region2.mp3.california', flag: false},
    {field: 'region2.mp3.california', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'region2.mp3.abc', flag: false}, 
    {field: 'region3.mp3.abc', flag: false}, 
];

var regions = ["region1.mp3", "region2.mp3","region3.mp3"];
var myArrayRegions = [];

//Create a new array with each element being the result of the callback function.
myArrayRegions = myArray.map(function(o){
  //o ==> {field: 'region1.mp3.california', flag: false}
  //o.field ==> region1.mp3.california
  //o.field.split('.') ==> ['region1','mp3','california']
  //o.field.split('.')[0] ==> 'region1'
  return o.field.split('.')[0];
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(myArrayRegions));

//Filter the array to remove duplicates
myArrayRegions = myArrayRegions.filter(function(item, pos, self){
  return self.indexOf(item) == pos;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(myArrayRegions));
```

**Note**

You are only comparing the length of both array. `myArray` may contain `region4`, `region5` and `region6` it will still return `true` because both array have a length of `3`

Comment: This worked.Can you please explain me your code little bit??

Comment: i am not getting this line :return o.field.split('.')[0];
}).filter(function(item, pos, self) {.Sorry i am bit poor on client side :)

Comment: @Learning I am simply chaining the functions. I updated the answer. If you don't understand it. Please read the documentation linked in my answer. it will help you

Comment: All right.thank you so much for your kind help and please keep helping like this :)

Comment: @Learning No problems ! Don't forget to read the documentation. It will help you to learn

Answer (score 1):

Try this reduce function call:

```
myArray.reduce(function(p, c) {
  var region = c.field.split(".")[0];
  return p.includes(region) == false ? p.concat(region) : p;
}, []).length;
```

Comment: This will create duplicates